# PHPMailer returning no Error But Not Sending any Email(Live Server)

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using this code:

```
<?php
require ('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'allthingsremainhere@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SetFrom('youcanreply@lishup.com', 'Reply It! - LishUp');
$mail->AddAddress('techgoeshere@gmail.com', 'Tech');
$mail->Subject  = 'First PHPMailer Message';
$mail->Body     = 'Hi! This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.';

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

It is returning 'Message has been Sent'.

My Email and Password is alright. That's not the problem.

**In Google Account: 2Factor Authorization is turned off and 'Allow Less secure app' is turned on**

I am using a Live Server hosted on Google Cloud. Please help me to solve this

Comment: Just add $mail->SMTPDebug = true; to get any errors while sending mail.

Comment: PhpMailer provides a method to change debugging levels, see here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Do you have access to your mail logs? Perhaps it is being rejected at the mail server.

Comment: @CountKyle Unfortunately, No. I dont have access to my mail logs

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Almost none of your code does anything because you commented out `isSMTP()`. That means that PHPMailer will send via PHP's `mail()` function, and none of your SMTP-related settings will be used. As a result, your message will not be sent through gmail, but via your local mail server instead, which will be silently accepting whatever you give it but then failing to relay it any further. If your sending domain is using gmail, it's likely that you will fail SPF checks, and your messages will never be delivered.

You can see exactly what has happened to your messages by reading your local mail server's log file, probably somewhere like `/var/log/mail.log`.

Comment: While you are on live server, isSMTP() will just throw a connection error

Comment: No, it will throw an error *if your server has a problem*, for example if your hosting provider blocks outbound SMTP. How to diagnose and fix problems like that is discussed in great detail in [the PHPMailer  troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host). There's nothing wrong with your script otherwise.

Comment: So post the error message!!!! Also show us what is in your mail server logs.

Comment: Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your connection to the SMTP server, probably a wrong port, username, password, encryption

Comment: Quite easily - most likely, your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP, which is very common. You can test for that using the advice in the troubleshooting guide I already referred you to, and by referring to your hosting provider's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

here we go , first uncomment this line

```
//$mail->isSMTP();
```

to

```
$mail->isSMTP();
```

then run your code , it will attempt to login your gmail account and if less secure app is on it will send email else you will get email alert by gmail, if you got gmail alert then less secure is not on then just go and turn on it and run your code again it will work fine.